# How to remove the u' and some other information from Ipython/Pandas output

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I've been reading the great Python for Data Analysis book and following its exercises along, but my outputs are not the same that the outputs shown in the book.

One of them happens when I want to print the indices of a data frame object. For example:

```
>>> data = Series(np.random.randn(10), index=[['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'],[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3]])
```

When I call data.index, I get a output different from the book. Here's the output shown in the book:

```
MultiIndex
[('a', 1) ('a', 2) ('a', 3) ('b', 1) ('b', 2) ('b', 3) ('c', 1)
('c', 2) ('d', 2) ('d', 3)]
```

And this is my output:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd'], [1, 2, 3]],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2]])
```

How do I configure either Ipython or Pandas to change the output formatting? At least the **u'** piece of string.

Edit: I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: It just means its a unicode string, it shouldn't affect any operations so it's a display thing, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855645/how-to-turn-unicode-strings-into-regular-strings

Comment: Also, that book is based on a somewhat older version of pandas and some things (like indexes) have changed in the meantime.  It shouldn't be a problem for the most part, as old ways of doing things will mostly continue to work even as better ways to do them are provided.  You can look at the release notes in the docs if you want to see how things have changed

Comment: your output is different from what you can see in the structure itself, see answer below. EdChum summarized about the unicode character before each string.

Comment: Using Python 3 would be one way to get rid of the `u` prefixes, though perhaps a bit of a drastic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this display if you do a `list` conversion:

```
data.index.tolist()

#[('a', 1L), ('a', 2L), ('a', 3L), ('b', 1L), ('b', 2L), ('b', 3L), ('c', 1L), ('c', 2L), ('d', 2L), ('d', 3L)]
```